# Create a mongo linq query with an array on object

Tags: mongodb, linq, asp.net-core

I'm using MongoDB
I try to make a linq query with a collection on my object. But I don't know how to do that.
On NodeJs code it's gonna a just populate function but on c#... ?

```
public class Users
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId? activity { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectId>? activityPerimeters { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Activities
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public ObjectId company { get; set; }
}
```

```
        var joinlist = (from i in mongoContext.Users
                        join a in mongoContext.Activities on i.activity equals a.Id

/// How I can make a join with a collection ?
                        join acs in mongoContext.Activities on i.activityPerimeters equals a.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            i,
                            a
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use below query, we could try to use contain method inside the second join.

Like below:

```
        List<Users> users   = new List<Users>();

        List<Activities> activities = new List<Activities>();


        var results = (from u in users
                       join a in activities on u.activity equals a.Id  
                       join ap in activities on u.activityPerimeters.Contains(a.Id) equals true
                       select new { User = u, Activity = a, ActivityPerimeter = ap }).ToList();
```

Comment: This work with a local list, like your code. But not with a context. MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException : 'Expression not supported: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.u.activityPerimeters.Contains(<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a.Id) because expression cannot be translated as a field path.'